# Splitting the octahedron

Tags: geometry

It is possible to split a regular tetrahedron into four regular tetrahedra and a regular octahedron.

[image]

Is it possible in turn to split a regular octahedron into smaller regular solids with equal edge length?

Comment: Yes, for instance into six octahedra and eight tetrahedra: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral-octahedral_honeycomb#/media/File:TetraOctaHoneycomb-VertexConfig.svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Intelligenti pauca for the reply.

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral-octahedral_honeycomb), one gets

[image]